# Missing records in a -6 table matrix

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, select

i would be grateful for any help in solving the problem below. I've restated the problem following a request for some data

I have the following sql tables

1. qual = List of qualification codes (qualcode, description) e.g.

   ```
   HSE-01  HSE INDUCTION
   HSE-02  SAFETY BRIEFING
   HSE-03  FIRST AID
   ```
2. labor = List of labor codes (laborcode, name)

   ```
   10072   John Doe
   10073   Jane Smith
   10074   Mark Twain
   ```
3. craft = List of craft codes (craft, desc)

   ```
   MECH   Mechanic
   ELEC   Electrician
   PLUM   Plumber
   ```
4. laborcraft = the craft attached to each labor code (laborcode, craft)

   ```
   10072   MECH
   10073   ELEC
   10074   PLUM
   ```
5. qualcraft = qualifications relevant to each craft (qualcode, craft)

   ```
   HSE-01   MECH
   HSE-02   ELEC
   HSE-03   PLUM
   ```
6. laborqual = actual qualifications of each labor id (laborcode, qualcode)

   ```
   10072   HSE-01
   10073   HSE-01
   10072   HSE-02
   10074   HSE-02
   ```

Each Qualification code may be relevant for one or many crafts, Each labor code has a single craft

From the data in table 5 above you can see that qualification HSE-03 is relevant for the PLUM craft and HSE-02 is relevant for the ELEC craft

However from table 6 (actual qualifications) we can see that

- Mark Twain is a PLUM craft but does not possess the HSE-03 qualification
- Jane Smith is an ELEC but does not possess the HSE-02 qualification.

I need to identify all the qualifications that SHOULD be held by each labor code but ARE NOT. the results should look like

```
    10073   HSE-02
    10074   HSE-03
```

I don't mind if labor codes have other qualifications that they don't need to have for example

```
    10072   HSE-02
    10073   HSE-01
    10074   HSE-02
```

I just need to know where we're missing the relevant qualifications

Thanks for any help

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text - not images. ([mcve].)

Comment: thanks jarlh, I have added some data - hope this is what you needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join `laborcraft` and `qualcraft`, and use `not exists` to flter on "missing" rows in `laborqual`:

```
select lc.laborcode, qc.qualcode
from laborcraft lc
inner join qualcraft qc on qc.craft = lc.craft
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from laborqual lq 
    where lq.laborcode = lc.laborcode and lq.qualcode = qc.qualcode
)
```

Comment: ok I ran that and it didn't work. I will give you the data that i checked where it gave an error.... give me an hour or so I have to go out first

Comment: if you can try with the following data and see what you get. 
qualcraft data
    HSE-01   ENG1
    HSE-01   ENG2

laborcraft data
    100075   ENG1
    100076   ENG1
    100077   ENG2

laborqual data
    100072   HSE-01
    100073   HSE-01
    100077   HSE-01

running your script did not identify that 10075 and 10076 as 'missing' records
thanks again

Comment: should mention its an oracle database - in case that makes a difference
tks

Comment: interestingly, if I run your query like this it works. i.e. it works for one qualification code at a time (sorry I can't get the code to format in this comment):
  
    select lc.laborcode, qc.qualcode
from laborcraft lc
inner join qualcraft qc on qc.craft = lc.craft
where qc.qualcode = 'HSE-01' and not exists (
    select 1 
    from laborqual lq 
    where lq.laborcode = lc.laborcode and lq.qualcode = qc.qualcode
)

Comment: seems i should apologise as i've been rather stupid! I had the number of results limited to 1000 and it wasnt able to return all the missing records.

Thanks very much that DOES work!